# How to get with useState an array object key, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-hooks, react-router

How to get with useState an array object key, React ? I'm expecting to set as a useState default value the status key. basically the isuue is for chenging the status value on select from a child component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-24-04-vp0v8m?file=/src/App.js

```jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TaskComponent from "./components/TaskComponent";

const Tasks = [
  {
    id: "001",
    status: 0,
    priority: 2,
    title: "Develop website homepage",
    description:
      "Create a visually appealing and responsive homepage for the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
    },
    author_name: "John Smith"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    status: 1,
    priority: 1,
    title: "Implement user authentication",
    description: "Add user authentication feature to the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-24T14:30:00"
    },
    author_name: "Sarah Lee"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");                   // set default status from Tasks array status
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState("");
  
  setStatus()        // set Status new value

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent
              Tasks={tasks}
              status={status}
              setStatus={setStatus}
              priority={priority}
              setPriority={setPriority}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You only need one or two states. You need an index of task (or id). Creating a separate state for `status` and `priority` is not good idea

Comment: This is the third or forth post with that same sandbox, are you crowdsourcing work for a project? Can you clarify what the specific issue is that you need help with in this post?

Comment: Thanks, the point is that I'm trying to change the individual task status and priority data (at the App component) with changing the select option in the child component TaskComponent. To reproduce - after clicking the individual task you can two selects to change the app component Tasks array data. I thought of passing the function as a prop or any other ideas would be helpfull. Could you please see the sandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass a single callback to the `TaskComponent` component that when called passes back a task object with the updated status and/or priority properties. This callback should update the `tasks` state. The `status` and `priority` states should be moved and updated in the `TaskComponent` component.

Example:

App

```
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);

  const changeTask = (task) => {
    setTasks((tasks) =>
      tasks.map((taskEl) => (taskEl.id === task.id ? task : taskEl))
    );
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          ....
          
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent tasks={tasks} changeTask={changeTask} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

TaskComponent

```
const TaskComponent = ({ tasks, changeTask }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(task?.status);
  const [priority, setPriority] = React.useState(task?.priority);

  const handleSaveTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // enqueue update with shallow task copy with updated properties
    changeTask({
      ...task,
      status,
      priority
    });

    history.push("/taskslist");
  };

  if (!task) {
    return <div>No Task</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
        <p>{task.description}</p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSaveTask}>
          <label>Status</label>
          <select
            value={status}
            onChange={(e) => setStatus(Number(e.target.value))}
          >
            <option value="select" disabled>
              Select Status
            </option>
            <option value="0">In queue</option>
            <option value="1">In progress</option>
            <option value="2">Completed</option>
          </select>
          <select
            value={priority}
            onChange={(e) => setPriority(Number(e.target.value))}
          >
            <option value="select" disabled>
              Select Priority
            </option>
            <option value="0">Low</option>
            <option value="1">Medium</option>
            <option value="2">High</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-with-usestate-an-array-object-key-react]